# Can't understand this "Unreachable code detected" error

Tags: c#

I have this snippet of code that is giving me problems.

The last break statements gives an error of "unreachable code detected"

this has caused a logical flaw in my program.

can someone identify the problem please?

thanks!

```
        case 127232:
            case1 = splited[0];
            changeRow[inServer] = "Audit Privileges and Logs:\n";
            changeRow[inServer + " Exception"] = "No Exception";
            writeToFile(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\" + inServer + "127232.txt", case1);


            if (case1.Contains("audit level;failure") || case1.Contains("audit level;all"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("success!");
                        changeRow[inServer + "Observations"] = changeRow[inServer + "Observations"] + "1) Audit options found .";
                        changeRow[inServer] = changeRow[inServer] + "string pattern audit level;failure or auditlevel;all found";
                        break;
                }

                else 
                {
                    //Audit Privileges should have been in enabled for sys and system accounts or the security administrator.
                    changeRow[inServer + "Observations"] = changeRow[inServer + "Observations"] + "1) No audit options found.";
                    changeRow[inServer] = changeRow[inServer] + "Correct audit options not configured!";
                    changeRow[inServer + " Exception"] = "Exception";
                    break;
                }
            break;
```

Comment: how about upvoting some answers and aceepting some?

Comment: The final break cannot be reached as both the if and else have a break.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a `break` in both your `if` and your `else` clause, meaning that the `break` at the bottom will never be reached.

It doesn't really matter in this particular case but it seems the compiler is not "smart" enough to figure that out. That's not necessarily a bad attitude for the compiler to take since this could be considered sloppy coding practice.

Just get rid of both `break` statements within the `if` and `else` clauses or, alternatively, refactor to:

```
case 127232:
    case1 = splited[0];
    changeRow[inServer] = "Audit Privileges and Logs:\n";
    changeRow[inServer + " Exception"] = "No Exception";
    writeToFile(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\" + inServer + "127232.txt", case1);

    if (case1.Contains("audit level;failure") || case1.Contains("audit level;all"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("success!");
        changeRow[inServer + "Observations"] = changeRow[inServer + "Observations"] + "1) Audit options found .";
        changeRow[inServer] = changeRow[inServer] + "string pattern audit level;failure or auditlevel;all found";
        break;
    }

    //Audit Privileges should have been in enabled for sys and system accounts or the security administrator.

    changeRow[inServer + "Observations"] = changeRow[inServer + "Observations"] + "1) No audit options found.";
    changeRow[inServer] = changeRow[inServer] + "Correct audit options not configured!";
    changeRow[inServer + " Exception"] = "Exception";
    break;
```

What you have in your original is not really that much different to something like:

```
if (someCondition) {
    doSomething();
    return;
} else {
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

which I always think is cleaner as:

```
if (someCondition) {
    doSomething();
    return;
}

doSomethingElse();
```

I don't like being tabbed to death by code unless it's absolutely necessary :-)

Comment: What did the compiler not figure out?

Comment: @CodeInChaos, it didn't figure out that the unreachable code was irrelevant. It's no different to the sequence `return; return;` - although the second `return` is unreachable in that case, it has no effect on the behaviour of the code.

Comment: Unreachable code has never an effect on the code. I'd expect `return; return;` to give exactly the same warning.

Comment: @Code, you're right of course about unreachable code never having an effect. Maybe I should have said "a likely intended effect". For example, while I'd consider double break or double return as harmless (though still worthy of questioning the coder's sanity), the sequence `return; x = 7; return;` I would be more circumspect about. Clearly the coder intended _something_ there (the first return probably should have been conditional somehow), just not sure what :-) Updated the answer to add that it probably _is_ a concern even though a double break _could_ be considered "harmless".

Answer (score 8):

Both the `then` and the `else` part of your `if` clause contain a `break`. So obviously the code after the `if` will never be executed.

Answer (score 3):

Because your code will go into either the `if` or the `else` and they both contain a `break`, which will take you outside of your `switch` statement, the last `break` statement is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

There are breaks in if Condition and Else condition. How can it reack break after else condition?